# Internal Server Error with Flask using Python

Tags: python, flask

Am trying to create a simple chatbot using python but anytime i run it i have internal server error. Below is the code. Could anyone help?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from  chatterbot import ChatBot
from  chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer


app = Flask(__name__)

englich_bot = ChatBot("Chatterbot", storage_adapter="chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter")
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(englich_bot)
trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('abcpage.html')

@app.route("/get")
def get_bot_response():
   userText = request.args.get('msg')
   return  str(englich_bot.get_response(userText))

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Answer (score 0):

[Receiving URL params](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#url-route-registrations) written in following:

```
@app.route("/get/<msg>")
def get_bot_response(msg):
   return  str(englich_bot.get_response(msg))
```

Path params can be gotten from request object, but this way is easy.